# mysql update from file insert if exist else update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table (my_table) which have 3 columns (Name, Age, Place). I have a new text file (data.txt tab separated data file) which have have 2 columns (Name and Place). I want to insert information from file "data.txt" into my_table with the condition if Name is same (in mysql table and in text file "data.txt") update row (insert Place value in 3rd column) otherwise create new row (in which Age will be NULL).

```
if NAME_my_tabe== Name_data.txt --> update this row (do Place_my_tabe = Place_data.txt)
if Name_data.txt not present in my_tabe --> create new row (do Name_my_table=Name_data.txt, Age_my_table=NULL, Place_my_tabe = Place_data.txt)
```

How to do this in mysql ??? (I want to insert values from text file)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure your table contains the following:

1. UNIQUE on Name
2. Age is NULLABLE

The following query will do what you need:

```
INSERT INTO my_table SET name = 'Name', place = 'Place' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE place = 'New Place'
```

With the code to read your file, you could use:

```
$file = new SplFileObject('data.txt');
while($file->eof() === true) {
  $line = $file->fgets();
  $data = explode("\t", $line);

  // execute query:
  $query = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO my_table SET name = '%1$s', place = '%2$s' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE place = '%2$s'",
    $data[0], // escape this
    $data[1] // escape this
  );
}
```

Note that you will need to execute that query using your mysql client library.

Comment: what about the text file data.txt? how to specify take data from this file?

Comment: You could open a new question for that (or update this one), make sure to tell how your file is formatted - or we won't be able to help.

Comment: I tried to edit question.. hope now it makes more sense. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: I need to know what the contents of your .txt file look like.

Comment: Its simple tab separated text file. An example line- John\tUSA